# Calculate probability distribution table for dates

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, discrete-data

I'm a software developer.  Over 10 weeks our team has had the following estimations/actuals for how much work we can complete in points:

```
       estimated  actual

Week 1    10       10
Week 2    10       8
Week 3    10       10
Week 4    10       10
Week 5    10       6
Week 6    10       12
Week 7    10       7
Week 8    10       10
Week 9    10       12
Week 10   10       12
```

The median actual output of the team is `9.7` points which I will treat as `10`.

The deviations are:

`10 - 10 = 0, 8 - 10 = -2, 0, 0, -4, 2, -3, 0, 2, 2.`

This gives us a variance of 4.01 which I will treat as 4.  And a standard deviation of 2.

Based on current data, I want to create a probability distribution that tells me the likelihood of finishing the next 100 points over finite time.

E.G. (sample)

```
1 week : 1%
2 weeks: 2%
3 weeks: 5%
4 weeks: 8%
5 weeks: 10%
6 weeks: 15%
7 weeks: 20%
8 weeks: 30%
9 weeks: 80%
10 weeks: 98%
11 weeks: 99.99%
12 weeks: 99.99999%
```

The limit as time approaches infinity is 100%.

I have explored continuous and discrete distributions.  Continuous graphs look nicer, but I only care about discrete bits of time (days or weeks).  I know my estimations/actuals, median, deviations, variance, and std deviation.

How can I continue on to get the result I'm looking for?  I am happy to use formulas from Excel or Numbers (mac version of excel).  I'm just not sure what to use to get the result I require.

Comment: What you want is $\text{Prob}[T_{100}<t]$ where the random variable $T_{100}$ is the time needed to do 100 points of work. The question is not so much if $t$ should be continuous or discrete but rather how you would model the distribution of $S$, the amount of points done in a week. OP suggests a *parametric* approach, i.e. $S$ is normally distributed with $\mu=10$ and $\sigma=2$. Another distribution is also possible, A *non-parametric* approach would for example be to use the empirical cdf of $S$. In either case, $\text{Prob}[T_{100}<t]=\text{Prob}[\sum_{i=i}^t S_i<100]$ can be calculated.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst - How can I calculate such a probability without using a program to loop a bunch of samples from a set?

Comment: I posted my full solution to this problem on github: https://github.com/pbrianmackey/EvidenceBasedScheduling

Comment: @Brian.Mackey: nice! But i see your program gives a probability of 100% that the work is done after 11 weeks or so. 100% ! So really *nothing* can go wrong, right? Although my solution with the normal distribution is equally in the dark about things that could seriously decrease your team's work speed in the future, it will never say "100%". :-)

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst - Yea, I'm not sure how to handle that issue.  We are never guaranteed to hit a date.  The unexpected is always a possibility.  That's actually part of the motivation behind the project (don't target a specific date, rather a date range).  I could say "99.99999%" or "statistically it doesn't make sense to keep projecting beyond date XYZ...".  I'm totally open to suggestions.  And yes I will look further into your solution and see how I can improve the app by integrating it.  I also welcome anyone to submit code to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple approach that makes minimal assumptions about the underlying process that generates the counts.

Take the set of observed counts $\{ 10, 8, 10, 10, 6, 12, 7, 10, 12, 12 \}$ and sample with replacement until the sum exceeds $100$.  Call the number of samples $n_1$.  Do this $m$ times where $m$ is as large as you like and obtain a sample $\{ n_i \}_{i=1}^{m}$.  You can use this sample to get an estimate of the distribution for how long it will take to complete $100$ points.

Then you could take the mean or median and use it as a crude estimate for how long you expect it to take, and the spread of this distribution gives you some information about how uncertain you are about your estimate.  There's still some unaccounted for uncertainty in the original sample (as well as in the simulation itself, although this is easily controlled), but this should at least give you some idea.

If you have access to R here is some code that does the simulation and generates a plot along with some interesting statistics:

```
iter = 10000
counts = c(10, 8, 10, 10, 6, 12, 7, 10, 12, 12)
weeks = NULL

for (i in 1:iter) {
    s = 0
    n = 0
    while (s < 100) {
        s = s + sample(counts, size=1)
        n = n + 1
    }
    weeks = c(weeks, n)
}

hist(weeks)
table(weeks) / sum(table(weeks))
mean(weeks)
median(weeks)
sd(weeks)
```

Comment: This is great.  The only problem is that it requires R.  I installed R and the output is amazing.  Now if only I can figure out how to translate this to excel/numbers.  I see it takes random samples and generates an estimate of the weeks based on the results of the sample data.  Most likely our team can produce 100 points in 11 weeks...makes sense.  I am still interested in a calculable/formula based approach I can use in Excel or as I understand it "non-parametric approach" as @StijnDeVuyst puts it.

Comment: I don't use Excel much for this sort of thing, but it should be possible to code the simulation there as well.  Another idea is to export `weeks` from R as a csv file which can then be opened in Excel.  You could do this using the command `write.table(weeks, file='/path/to/file/weeks.csv', sep=',', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: Ultimately I used a solution close to this.

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The Monte Carlo simulation suggested by dsaxton is a great solution of the "non-parametric" kind. A (possible) parametric solution would be the following. Suppose you are willing to assume that the amount of points $S_i$ done in week $i$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, that is, normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Assume also that all $S_i$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ are jointly independent, i.e. the number of points done in one week has no bearing on the number of points done in any of the other weeks. Then, it is known that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^t S_i  \sim N(t\mu,t\sigma^2)
$$
so the amount of points done in $t$ weeks is also normally distributed. Then standardisation yields
\begin{align*}
\text{Prob}[\text{100 points get done in } t \text{ weeks}]
& = 1-\text{Prob}[\sum_{i=1}^t S_i \leqslant 100]\\
& = 1-\text{Prob}[\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^t S_i) - t\mu }{\sqrt{t}\sigma} \leqslant \frac{100-t\mu}{\sqrt{t}\sigma}]\\
& = 1-\Phi\big(\frac{100-t\mu}{\sqrt{t}\sigma}\big)
\end{align*}
Here, $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution which even Excel knows (NORM.S.DIST). The values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ can be estimated from the observed "points per week" (10,8,10,10,6,12,7,10,12,12) by calculating their sample mean (AVERAGE) and sample variance (VAR.S). The nice thing about the formula is that you can also use it for a noninteger number of weeks $t$ in the future, say for example after $t=2.7$ weeks.